# Angular 2 Navigate to Internal Anchor Link

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm attempting to do deep-linking in an Angular 2 component to open a tab when a URL parameter is set. Example:

`http://my.project/tabs/2`

This would then trigger my component to load tab #2 on page load instead of the default tab #1.

I also need to change the current URL to `http://my.project/tabs/2` when Tab #2 is clicked while on the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use URLs you'll need [router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). Once you setup your routing, you can use router in your components. Let's say you have these routes:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/tabs', name: 'Tabs', component: TabsComponent },
  { path: '/tabs/:id', name: 'TabDetails', component: TabDetailsComponent },
])
```

then in your component you can do something like this:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
  // this will handle initial opening, or browser refresh
  let initial: any = this._router.subscribe(route => {
    let tabID = route.replace('tabs/', ''); // or something smarter please (;
    this.openTabs(tabID);
    initial.unsubscribe();
  });
}
openTabs(id) {
  if (!check_if_its_initial) {
    this._router.navigate(['Tabs', 'TabDetails', {id: id}]);
  }
}
```

Comment: After I posted this I solved the routing issue, but different from your answer I used the constructor(params: RouteParams) { var test = params.get('id'); } method. It seems better than grabbing the data through string manipulation. Is there a reason why you didn't use params.get() ?

Comment: @AJStacy TBH, didn't think about it at the time. Had something like this in my code (didn't have params there...), so I thought it could work for you. But as I said in the comment - I'm glad you did 'something smarter' (: